# Show that $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)$ converges and find the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

> Let $a>0$ and $x_0\in I=\left (\frac{1}{2a}, \frac{3}{2a}\right )$. Show that the sequence $(x_n)$, $n\geq 0$, $$x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n), \quad n \geq 0$$ converges. Which is the limit? 
> **Hint:** Consider $\phi (x)=x(2-ax)$ and show that $\phi (I)\subset \left [\frac{3}{4a}, \frac{1}{a}\right ]$.

---

So that I understand  that correctly, with the hint we want to show that $\phi(x)$ is bounded and monotonic, which means that the sequence converges?

We have the following: \begin{align*}\frac{1}{2a}<x< \frac{3}{2a} &\Rightarrow a\cdot \frac{1}{2a}<ax<a\cdot  \frac{3}{2a}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}<ax< \frac{3}{2} \Rightarrow -\frac{3}{2}<-ax< -\frac{1}{2}\\ & \Rightarrow 2-\frac{3}{2}<2-ax< 2-\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}<2-ax< \frac{3}{2} \\ & \Rightarrow x\cdot \frac{1}{2}<x(2-ax)< x\cdot \frac{3}{2}\\ & \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2a}\cdot \frac{1}{2}<x\cdot \frac{1}{2}<x(2-ax)< x\cdot \frac{3}{2}< \frac{3}{2a}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\\ & \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4a}<x(2-ax)< \frac{9}{4a}\end{align*}

That is not the interval that we want to get. Do we have to do that maybe using derivatives?

Comment: For $a>1$ apply fixed point theorem.

Comment: **Hint:** $\phi(x)$ has a maximum at $x_m=\frac{1}{a}$ and $\phi(x_m)=x_m$. Thus $\phi(x)\leq \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: Would you please tell me the book's name? I want to practice that.

Answer (score 3):

Complete the square on the right side to find
$$
1-ax_{n+1}=(1-ax_n)^2
$$
so that the convergence of $y_n=1-ax_n$ is very easy to discuss (subsequence of a geometric sequence).

Comment: Do we not use the given hint in that way?

Comment: The hint can only be used by using the square, $|1-ax_n|<\frac12$, $(1-ax_n)^2<\frac14$, $0\le 1-ax_{n+1}<\frac14$, $\frac3{4a}<x_{n+1}\le\frac1a$. So instead of going back-and-forth between $x_n$ and $y_n$ you can also just examine the $y_n$ sequence and translate its results back to the $x_n$ sequence.

Comment: Ah ok,sowe don't need to consider the function $\phi(x)$, do we?

Comment: You would need to have to write it as $\phi(x)=\frac1a(1-(1-ax)^2)$. Interval arithmetic works better if the formula is more compact, does contain fewer separate occurrences of the input variables. You could also do a curve discussion of $\phi$ over the interval, computing its local minima and maxima and thus the range of values.

Answer (score 1):

> **P1.** $\phi(x)$ has a maximum at $x_m=\frac{1}{a}$ and $\phi(x_m)=x_m$. Thus $\phi(x)\leq \frac{1}{a}$.

---

> **P2.** $\phi(x)$ is ascending on $\left(-\infty,\frac{1}{a}\right]$ and descending on $\left(\frac{1}{a},\infty\right)$.

Since $\phi'(x)=2-2ax$

---

> **P3.** For $x\in\left[\frac{1}{2a},\frac{3}{2a}\right] \Rightarrow
> \phi(x)\in\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right]$

Since $\frac{1}{2a}<\frac{1}{a}<\frac{3}{2a}$ and considering **Pr2**

- if $x\in\left[\frac{1}{2a},\frac{1}{a}\right] \Rightarrow \phi(x)\geq\phi\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)=\frac{3}{4a}$
- if $x\in\left[\frac{1}{a},\frac{3}{2a}\right] \Rightarrow \phi(x)\geq\phi\left(\frac{3}{2a}\right)=\frac{3}{4a}$

And from **Pr1**, $\phi(x)\in\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right]$.

---

> **Pr4.** $\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right]\subset\left[\frac{1}{2a},\frac{3}{2a}\right]$

Since
$\frac{1}{2a}<\frac{3}{4a}<\frac{1}{a}<\frac{3}{2a}$.

---

> **Pr5.** $\phi(x)$ is a [contraction map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) on $\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right]$.

Since $$\forall x\in\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right] \overset{Pr4}{\Rightarrow}
x\in\left[\frac{1}{2a},\frac{3}{2a}\right] \overset{Pr3}{\Rightarrow} 
\phi(x)\in\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right]$$
[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) $\exists \epsilon$ in between $x,y$ such that
$$|\phi(y)-\phi(x)|=|\phi'(\epsilon)|\cdot|y-x|=
|2-2a\epsilon|\cdot|y-x|\leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot|y-x|$$

---

**Summary**. Although $x_0$ may not fall inside $\left[\frac{3}{4a},\frac{1}{a}\right]$ (as seen in **Pr4**), $x_1=\phi(x_0)$ does (as seen in **Pr3**). And so does any $x_n$ for $\forall n\geq 1$ (as seen in **Pr5**). Applying Banach fixed-point theorem, the limit exists and it's a solution of
$$L=L(2-aL)$$